# c# Low Level Input Decode Message Params

Tags: c#, raw-input, low-level

I am making a low level keyboard hook that processes global key presses, forwarding this to the Raw Input API to check what keyboard device it came from.

I do this by using the `SendMessage` function in my hook that can be received by the API.

My issue is that the API cannot read the buffer of the lParam, returning false

`>> Error getting the rawinput buffer`

How can I adapt the hook to allow that message's lParam to be successfully decoded by the API?

(I am using the Rawkeyboard struct and I feel like this may not be the correct one to use, I also tried using some others with no luck)

**Hook**

```
//^ DLL Imports, SetWindowsHookEx, etc^

public int HookProc(int Code, int wParam, ref CWPRETSTRUCT lParam) {
    if (Code >= 0) {
        // Block
        Rawkeyboard lParamKeyboard = new Rawkeyboard();
        int result = SendMessage(Handle, 0x00FF, wParam, ref lParamKeyboard ); // Send to API
        if (result == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // Allow
    return CallNextHookEx(Handle, Code, wParam, ref lParam);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rawkeyboard {
    public ushort Makecode;                 // Scan code from the key depression
    public ushort Flags;                    // One or more of RI_KEY_MAKE, RI_KEY_BREAK, RI_KEY_E0, RI_KEY_E1
    private readonly ushort Reserved;       // Always 0    
    public ushort VKey;                     // Virtual Key Code
    public uint Message;                    // Corresponding Windows message for exmaple (WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYASKEYDOWN etc)
    public uint ExtraInformation;           // The device-specific addition information for the event (seems to always be zero for keyboards)

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("Rawkeyboard\n Makecode: {0}\n Makecode(hex) : {0:X}\n Flags: {1}\n Reserved: {2}\n VKeyName: {3}\n Message: {4}\n ExtraInformation {5}\n",
                                            Makecode, Flags, Reserved, VKey, Message, ExtraInformation);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CWPRETSTRUCT {
    IntPtr lResult;
    IntPtr lParam;
    IntPtr wParam;
    uint message;
    IntPtr hWnd;
}
```

**API**

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message){
        switch (message.Msg){
            // Message Received!
            case 0x00FF:{
                bool result = false;
                hdevice = message.LParam;
                if (_deviceList.Count == 0) return false;
                var dwSize = 0;

                Win32.GetRawInputData(hdevice, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, IntPtr.Zero, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rawinputheader)));
                if (dwSize != Win32.GetRawInputData(hdevice, DataCommand.RID_INPUT, out _rawBuffer, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Rawinputheader)))){
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error getting the rawinput buffer");
                    result = false;
                }
                else{
                    // Do checks here
                    result = true;
                }
                message.Result = (IntPtr)Convert.ToInt32(result);
            }
            break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rawinputheader
{
    public uint dwType;                     // Type of raw input (RIM_TYPEHID 2, RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD 1, RIM_TYPEMOUSE 0)
    public uint dwSize;                     // Size in bytes of the entire input packet of data. This includes RAWINPUT plus possible extra input reports in the RAWHID variable length array. 
    public IntPtr hDevice;                  // A handle to the device generating the raw input data. 
    public IntPtr wParam;                   // RIM_INPUT 0 if input occurred while application was in the foreground else RIM_INPUTSINK 1 if it was not.

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("RawInputHeader\n dwType : {0}\n dwSize : {1}\n hDevice : {2}\n wParam : {3}", dwType, dwSize, hDevice, wParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `if (Win32.GetRawInputData(...) != dwSize` and confirm if you still get the error?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 yes, still the same error, switching the operator behind has no effect, thanks though! :)

Comment: Capture the result of first api and check last error? `var result = Win32.GetRaw...(); if (result == -1) { var code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); var error = new Win32Exception(code); Debug.WriteLine(code + ":" + error.ToString()); }` Check if this gives you anything.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I got a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid` error, this must relate to @shingo 's responce

Answer (score 2):

The type of `lParam` for `HookProc` and `SendMessage(WM_INPUT)` are different.

For `HookProc`, it's [CWPRETSTRUCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagcwpretstruct) structure.

For `SendMessage(WM_INPUT)`, it's [RAWINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagrawinput) structure.

So you need to create a new `RAWINPUT` object then pass to the `SendMessage` method.

Comment: Hey, can you look at my edits to see if they are what you suggested, still getting the same error ;(

Comment: I'm wrong, send WM_INPUT message need RAWINPUT structure, it contains RAWKEYBOARD structure.